I encountered a problem when i write a simple asynchornous function to update a data in MonogDB
i was trying to implement a javascript asynchornous code which can be able to update a data with the specified ID in MongoDB like this but as a result i got nothing as an output i dont know why?
async function updateCourse(id){
    const course = await Course.findById(id)
    if(!course) return;
    course.set({
        isPublished: true,
        author: "Samuel"
    })

    const result = await course.save()
    console.log(result)
}

updateCourse('5a68fdf95db93f6477053ddd') 

i was trying to update one specific course with the specified id that's passed inside the async function as a parameter but in return i got nothing there is indeed a course with that specified id i write the if conditional statement to check if the course with that id exists it does exist so it should set the new course author but it didnt.

Make sure you are comparing the same datatype; i.e. not comparing strings to ObjectIds. Also, did you await the updateCourse function?

what do you mean i didnt compare anything and i also didnt await the function updateCourse?

The updateCourse function seems to take an input of string. While you are using this string input to findById, which _id is usually an ObjectId type. The datatype mismatch will result in no data return. On the other hand, when you call the async function updateCourse, you didn't await the return of the function. It could be another potential cause for your issue of having no data returned.

okay thank you so much i will try to fix the datatype mismatch if that's actually the problem.
